# What is the purpose of defining both <summary> and <value> in a C# automatically implemented property?

Tags: c#, documentation

The C# specification/StyleCop (not sure which) suggests that an auto-property be annotated with two tags -- `<summary>` and `<value>`, giving something like:

```
class Foo
{
    /// <summary>Gets bar.</summary>
    /// <value>Bar.</value>
    public Example Bar { get; set; }
}
```

But for all practical purposes, the value of `<summary>` is always `Gets <whatever you said for value here\>.`

Is the separate tag here to help out a specific documentation generator, or have something to do with the way the compiler stamps out auto-properties, or something else?

Comment: if you think out of the box, then for those who use this properties the fact that they are automatically implemented is not known. Just playing advocate of the devil here...

Comment: I think it's just a rule.  Interestingly, Microsoft provides an example that looks like this: `<value>The Name property gets/sets the _name data member.</value>`, which would be useless for automatic properties.  Visual Studio doesn't automatically add this tag.

Comment: @Robert: Visual Studio doesn't automatically add things which will pass StyleCop in the general case.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  If you're saying that Visual Studio can't figure out that it's a property, maybe you're right.

Comment: @Robert: No, I mean that Visual Studio's autodoc generator doesn't care about the C# spec or StyleCop. StyleCop will fail for all kinds of things Visual Studio is happy with. For instance, if a property with a public getter and private setter doesn't being with the string `Gets ` then StyleCop will throw errors.

Answer (score 3):

The auto-suggested contents of these two tags are redundant, as you point out.
However, the text you would put in these two tags should be different for a well documented class, for example as part of a public API.

For example, let's have a look at Microsoft's public API documenation for the [DateTime.Date property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx).

The `<summary>` and the `<value>` tags in the comment correspond to two different sections of the documentation. In this case, the docs might have been generated from a comment like:

```
/// <summary>
///   Gets the date component of this instance.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
///   A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value
///   set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).
/// </value>
```

So you can see that the "summary", which is used in tooltips, is an abbreviated summary of the property, whereas the "value" is a more detailed description of the value returned.

Read the full documentation of the [<summary>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx) and [<value>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azda5z79.aspx) tags for more details.

Comment: Ah. So what I was putting in the summary tag is wrong then. I was saying `<summary>Gets a new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).`